# How can I call notepad.exe from a C program?

Tags: c, windows, file-io, process

i have written a time table program in c

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h> 
void main()
{
  int i=0;
  int selection;
  char day[20];
  char sub1[20];
  char sub2[20];
  char sub3[20];
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen("aa.txt","w");
  textcolor(5);
  textbackground(3);
  clrscr();
  while(i<3)
  {
    printf("Enter the day ");
    scanf("%s",day);
    printf("Enter the period 12.30-1:30 ");
    scanf("%s",sub1);
    printf("Enter the period 1.35-2.40 ");
    scanf("%s",sub2);
    printf("Enter the period 2.45-3.50 ");
    scanf("%s",sub3);
    fprintf(fp,"\n %s TIMETABLE IS AS FOLLOWS\n",day);
    fprintf(fp,"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
    fprintf(fp,"|~~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~~~|\n");
    fprintf(fp,"| TIME    | 12.30-1.30    | 1.35-2.40    |2.45-3.50 |\n");
    fprintf(fp,"|~~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~~~|\n");
    fprintf(fp,"| SUBJECT *     %s     * %s  * %s|\n",sub1,sub2,sub3);
    fprintf(fp,"|~~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~~~|\n");
    i++;
  }
  printf(" Time table has been Created in the File aa.txt successfully");
  getch();
}
```

when i finish the timetable . the time table is created in a.txt file. i want that file to be opened and show me automatically in a notepad. how to program that in c?

Comment: Opening another application is platform specific. Usually you do an OS API call for that

Comment: There's no way to do that in standard C, you have to resort to some platform-specific API (or exploit the platform-specific behavior of the `system` function). On which platform are you working?

Comment: @mbx how to find what API call to be used. i am using windows xp

Comment: @Matteo Italia: he mentioned notepad, its clear he is on windows.

Comment: @Matteo italia .i am working in windows xp intel dual core processor.

Comment: @Dani _a notepad_ could be anything Notepad++, UltraEdit, gedit, mcedit...

Comment: remember to call `fclose()` on file pointer.

Comment: Please indent your code. It will help you tremendously once you start writing more complex programs.

Comment: @ask22 you may find the [API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) relevant

Comment: @Dani: if he said `notepad` I'd agree with you, but he said "a notepad", which is often used as generic name for a simple text editor.

Comment: It's `int main(void)`, not `void main()`.

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
system("notepad.exe aa.txt");
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use `%windir%/notepad.exe` as a notepad.exe `.` would be preferred.

Comment: @Dani the system("notepad.exe aa.txt") is not working me. any reason for that?

Comment: @mbx: Definitely don't do that. Notepad is not always in the Windows directory. You have the right idea about not using hard-coded paths, but in this specific case, it's probably better to open the Notepad in the path.

Comment: @ask22: It won't work for you if the application `notepad.exe` is not in your path. There's an easy way to test that will isolate out any problems specific to your code. Open up the "Run" dialog from your Start menu, and type `notepad.exe aa.txt`. If it works, then your code is the problem. If not, then your system is configured differently and the code is probably fine.

Comment: @Cody Gray "notepad.exe aa.txt" in run dialog it prompts for me to "whether to create the file aa.txt"??

Comment: @ask22: Right, so it works. It opens Notepad and asks you to create the file because `aa.txt` doesn't exist. The same thing should happen when you run your application using the line `system("notepad.exe aa.txt");`. Does it not?

Comment: @CodyGray let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2463/discussion-between-ask22-and-cody-gray)

Comment: @Cody Gray when i run through program it does not ask me anything. it does not open even the empty notepad

Comment: `system` should definitely be avoided for a million reasons I already explained in several posts.

Comment: @ask: Sorry, I don't do chat... If you haven't solved your problem yet, update your question with more details.

Answer (score 8):

Dani already described the easier way (using `system`), so I'll just describe the other (more complicated but also more flexible) way to do it using the [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433218%28VS.85%29.aspx). Browsing the API (Overview -> System Services -> Processes and Threads), there's a small example on how to [create a process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682512%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) using the CreateProcess() function. In your case:

```
CreateProcess("notepad.exe",   // Name of program to execute
    "aa.txt",                  // Command line
    NULL,                      // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,                      // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,                     // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,                         // No creation flags
    NULL,                      // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,                      // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,                       // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi);                      // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
```

And then wait for the Notepad process to exit, as described in the example.

Comment: Note that while this may perhaps be the more complicated way, it is definitely the *recommended* way of doing it on Windows. Don't use `system` unless you absolutely *have* to.

Comment: Great.  Though in my situation (C++/CX) the first argument had to be the full path to notepad.exe, and the 2nd argument had to have the full command line, which includes not the just the argument, but also the executable.

Answer (score 5):

Third way: use the [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shell function telling to the shell to "just open the file" with the default editor:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>

// ...

if(ShellExecute(
    NULL,     // No parent window for error message boxes/...
    "open",   // Shell action ("verb") to be performed on the file (as opposed to "print", "explore", ...)
    "aa.txt", // File to be opened
    NULL,     // Command-line parameters - not used when opening documents
    NULL,     // Working directory - the current one is used by default
    SW_SHOW   // State of the window of the application being launched - SW_SHOW is the default
    )<=(HINSTANCE)32     // If ShellExecute returns a value <=32 it means that an error has occurred
   )
{
    puts("Cannot open aa.txt with the default editor - ShellExecute failed.");
}
```

This will open `aa.txt` with the default editor for `txt` files.

In my opinion, this is the best solution:

- it respects the user's choice for the editor (unlike `CreateProcess`, which just opens `notepad.exe`); if I set PSPad as the default editor for txt files, it will pop up PSPad and not notepad.
- it doesn't have problems with search paths for the editor (where is `notepad.exe`?)
- its behavior is fully defined, unlike the `system` function, which relies on `command.com`/`cmd.exe`, which have subtle differences between Windows versions and don't give you any documented/easy way to check if the operation succeeded;
- it doesn't give you any "false feeling of portability" like the `system`, that will happily compile on a Linux machine but will simply not work at runtime.