# c++ win32 open output file

Tags: c++, windows, file, output

I just finished making software where given an input of a .jpg file, the program creates an output in .txt format.

Currently, the program creates the output and terminates, so the user has to manually find and open the output file. Is there a way that upon creation of the output file, that the program then opens it automatically?

By this I mean the program would open the output.txt file using notepad, just as if the user double clicked it himself. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This question and answer might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057174/how-can-i-call-notepad-exe-from-a-c-program

Comment: `just as if the user double clicked it himself` See WinAPI [ShellExecute()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

**One can use the system () command. This invokes the system command processor.**

You can give it the command that should be run in the cmd. This is not a efficient solution as system is not good for the efficiency and security of the program, if you are intending to use the code for some commercial build, using system is not recommended, for hobby programs you can surely use it.

Lets say that the file is picture.txt at location C:/file
Your code will be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{ 
  system ("notepad.exe c:/file/picture.txt");
   return 0;
 }
```